# If isset For Multiple Submission Buttons

Tags: php, form-submit

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to run the code below, which I'm using with a form with multiple `submit buttons`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type']){
    if ($_POST['type'] == 'view'){
     $url = 'updatelocation.php';

    }   elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'finds'){
        $url = 'addfinds.php';

    }   elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'image'){

    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run this, I receive the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/locationsaction.php on line 2`

I've been reading some tutorials, for example [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html), and my code seems to match the example so I'm not sure where the error is.

For additional information, the buttons and form which I use to trigger the php script are shown below:

```
<form name="locations" id="locations" method="post" action="locationsaction.php">   

<td><div align="center"><input name="viewdetails" type="submit" value="view"/></div>/td>
<td><div align="center"><input name="addfinds" type="submit" value="finds"/></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><input name="addimages" type="submit" value="images"/></div></td>
```

I just wondered whether someone could look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
if (isset($_POST['type']) {
```

Should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
```

You are also missing a closing bracket on the last line. You should really try to format and indent your code properly. That will make it so much easier to spot errors like this. Consider this example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    if ($_POST['type'] == 'view') {
        $url = 'updatelocation.php';
    } elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'finds') {
        $url = 'addfinds.php';
    } elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'image'){
        $url = 'image.php';
    }

    header("Location: " . $url);
}
```

Another way to do the lookup is to use a map:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $urls = array(
        'view' => 'updatelocation.php',
        'finds' => 'addfinds.php',
        'image' => 'image.php'
    );
    $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
```

That's pretty clean - right? Adding a new case to this is simply a matter of adding it to the array.

Comment: Hi @alexn, thank you very much for this. This is really helpful. I'll accept your answer once the allotted time has past. Kind regards

Comment: @alexn Yep, caught that missing bracket as well. Good eye ;-)

Comment: @alexn The map thing; pretty slick ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `)` after `isset($_POST['type'])` - you aren't closing the `if` statement.

Comment: Hi @Kolink, thank you for this, and for taking the time to help me out. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You are also missing a closing brace:

```
 if (isset($_POST['type'])){ 
   if ($_POST['type'] == 'view'){ 
     $url = 'updatelocation.php'; 
   }elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'finds'){ 
     $url = 'addfinds.php'; 
   }elseif ($_POST['type'] == 'image'){ 
     $url='image.php';
   }
   header("Location: " . $url); 
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Bonzo, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and help. It's greatly appreciated. Kind regards